# Как получить логин и хост подключения к бд EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

В MS-SQL с помощью `suser_name()` я могу получить текущий логин, а `host_name()` даст мне хост. Как это можно сделать в C# используя EF Core 6?

Comment: выполните запрос к базе с помощью SqlQuery()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EF 6.0**
выполнив запрос через `Database.SqlQuery()`:

```
using (var ctx = new YourDBEntities())
{
    string hostName = ctx.Database
        .SqlQuery<string>("SELECT host_name() as hostname")
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**Database.SqlQuery** Метод:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

**EF Core:**

Можно , используя `CreateCommand()`:

```
using (var db = new YourDbContext()) 
{
    using (var command = db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT host_name() as hostname, suser_name() as username";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        db.Database.OpenConnection();

        using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (result.Read())
            {
                string hostName = (string)reader[0];
                string userName = (string)reader[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SqlQuery<string>` это какая версия EF? У меня нет такого метода у `Database`

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0   - EF6, как вы и указали

Comment: Это для .net core или для .net framework?

Comment: вопрос изначально был про EF 6, про Core уточнили уже после моего ответа

Comment: согласен, извиняюсь, совсем забыл про существование .net framework

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var ctx = new DbContext())
{
    var builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        ConnectionString = ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString
    };
    var user = builder["user id"];
    var dataSource = builder["data source"];

    var workstationID = (ctx.Database.Connection as SqlConnection).WorkstationId;
}
```

Остальные доступные ключи можно посмотреть в списке Keys в builder.
workstationID - это имя хоста.

Upd: для использования DbConnectionStringBuilder нужно подключить System.Data.Common, для SqlConnection - System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: Примечание: ответ дан для EF6 из изначального вопроса.